# Can we send amount to spacific account depend on order?

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway, razorpay, paytm

in my app, we have multiple franchises can we send money to a specific account depending on from where we got the order? Does any payment gateway provide this kind of solution?

ex. we have 4 franchises a,b,c,d and we received the order for `a` so payment should go to franchise `a`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Stripe, then yes they have [Destination Charge](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/destination-charges) and [Separate Charges and Transfers](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/separate-charges-and-transfers). Their Docs should be able to explain the fund flow you are looking for.